# tmux vim and c-space

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

I recently thought about switching from gvim to tmux+vim, however I got problem with vim accepting C-Space and C-Backspace.

I use these keysbindings since years to switch through my buffers, but when using vim in tmux these strokes are simply ignored.

I tried using

```
unbind Space
unbind C-Space
unbind -n Space
unbind -n C-Space
unbind -a Space
unbind -a C-Space
```

interestingly (but that is another matter) the latter two give me

```
/home/xxx/.tmux.conf:45: usage: unbind-key [-acn] [-t key-table] key
/home/xxx/.tmux.conf:46: usage: unbind-key [-acn] [-t key-table] key
```

(can anyone explain to me why "unbind -a key" does not work?).

Well - to sum things up: I'd really like to use tmux, but all googling into the C-Space problem brought me nowhere and without solving this problem I'd rather stick to gvim...

Greetings,
Richard

Comment: What gives `echo $TERM`?

Comment: that would be "screen-256color"

Comment: `unbind -a` is for removing *all* bindings, so it does not make sense to also provide a key argument.

Comment: @Chris: You are completely right. However then I'd consider the usage line wrong (either use alternatives or say "[key]" and explain) - I really take those serious ;)

Answer (score 1):

For reasons beyond my comprehension, Vim doesn't get `<C-Space>`, it gets `<C-@>` so you only need to use `<C-@>` instead of `<C-Space>` in your mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-@> <whatever>
```

You won't fix that problem on tmux's side.

Comment: Ah - it's a vim matter; the conclusion "works in gvim" => "works in vim" was indeed not that smart. Thank you - it helps a lot I guess...